# How can I edit in FCPX like I would for a live event when I have multiple sync'd tracks of the same event?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

I have layered up multiple clips of the same event in FCPX on the same timeline and synced the audio between clips.

I would like to view a certain layer at a certain point in the clip and select a few seconds of that clip to be visible, then switch to another layer, find another clip segment and make that visible. It would be very much like broadcasting live video where the director can select one or another camera and switch to that camera for broadcast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multicam clips do exactly what you're asking.  There's a good tutorial on how to use them [here](http://www.fcp.co/final-cut-pro/tutorials/1212-the-best-fcpx-multicam-demo-i-ve-ever-seen-ben-consoli-presents-at-the-the-boscpug).

Comment: well well.. whaddayaknow? another thing to learn in fcpx. #groan.. thanks, jason. =)

Comment: and a question: do you know if there is a way to convert a project into a multicam clip?

Comment: answer: no. gotta re-do the project as a multi cam clip.